# iOS App - Users table/model (to support both manual signup and Auth0)

Tags: ios, mongodb, authentication, model, database

I am creating an iOS app, and am working through the signup/login flow trying to understand how to structure my user model.

I want to allow users to sign up via facebook/twitter as well as using a standalone email/password if they don't want to authenticate through a service.

I am using auth0 to handle service authentication.

What is the standard process of storing / keeping track of my users if some are signing up through email/password, and others are simply authenticating through Auth0.

This is what I've come to so far:

My user model will contain the following properties at a minimum:

- _id
- name
- email
- password (will be blank for authenticated users)
- auth0_id (will be blank for non-authenticated users)

How I will validate a user on login:

- If a user who signs up manually (email/password) wants to log back in, I will check their email exists in my users table and then run a match on their password, if a match - return the user object.
- If a user who authenticates through a service wants to log back in, I will make the call to Auth0, check their auth0_id exists in my users table, and then run return the user object.

  - Does this pose any security issues?

Comments/suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend decoupling your user and auth0 models from each other. For example:

**User schema:**

- _id
- name
- email
- password

**Auth0 schema:**

- _id
- auth0_id
- user_id

I also recommend requiring a password on the user schema, and generating a strong password for users that register through Auth0. This will ensure that all users have a "standard" user account regardless of Auth0 and their continuing to have those services in the future (ex: the user deletes their Facebook account but continues to use your service – all they have to do is run through your "forgot password" flow).

Then have a standard login flow and an Auth0 login flow – the latter is the standard Auth0 flow, you check that the Auth0 ID exists and return the joined user record.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using the email/password functionallity that is built-in in Auth0? That way you don't have to keep two different logics.

Comment: Yes, that would make it easier. I believe there is an added cost from auth0 for me to use this feature. I agree this is a solution, but let's assume I don't want to go down this path...